# What is the difference between symbolize_key method and other methods to symbolize hash keys in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does the conversion of string keys to symbols differ in any way if we use any method like symbolize_keys!() or deep_symbolize_keys() or deep_symbolize_keys!() than if we use symbolize_keys() to do the same. I am asking this because i get a security warning for using symbolize_keys() method but not if I use any other method to do the same. I have googled a lot but I am not able to figure out what the difference is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `symbolize_keys` and `deep_symbolize_keys` is, the second one will work for nested hashes where the former one will not.

For example:

```
hash = { 'person' => { 'name' => 'Rob', 'age' => '28' } }

hash.symbolize_keys
# => {:person=>{"name"=>"Rob", "age"=>"28"}}

hash.deep_symbolize_keys
# => {:person=>{:name=>"Rob", :age=>"28"}}
```

And using `!` is a convention to modify `self`.

For example:

```
# without bang(!), hash is not affected
hash.deep_symbolize_keys # => {:person=>{:name=>"Rob", :age=>"28"}}
hash # => {"person"=>{"name"=>"Rob", "age"=>"28"}}

# with bang(!), hash is affected
hash.deep_symbolize_keys! # => {:person=>{:name=>"Rob", :age=>"28"}}
hash # => {:person=>{:name=>"Rob", :age=>"28"}}
```

Comment: I got that much but what I can't get is why I am getting a security warning for symbolize_key() but not if I use any of the other 3 methods to do the same thing

Comment: @SaumyaPant, what is the warning?

Comment: I get a denial of service warning

Comment: @SaumyaPant, right now I do not have any explanation regarding denial of service warning while using `symbolize_keys`. But then you should use `deep_symbolize_keys`.

Comment: I just wanted to know why its working that way. Anyways, Thanks for help. If you are able to get the logic, please post.